# Calculate function after function execution finished - data result exists not return always correct result

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-promise

That's not really the case of using promisses - because the result is a result of many service calls - in rder to fill an array of car.Make

```
<td ng-show="IsOK(obj)" class="text-center">
    <img ng-show="GetStatus(obj)==''" src='@Url.Content("~/img/spinner.gif")' />
    <span class="label label-success" ng-bind="GetStatus(obj)"></span>
</td>

 IsValid = (car: Car): boolean => {

        return (car.Title != null && car.Title != '' &&
            car.Condition != null &&
            car.StartDate < car.EndDate);
    }

    GetStatus = (car: Car): string => {

        if (!this.IsValid(car)) {
            return "Invalid";
        }

        if (car.Make == null)
        {
            return '';
        }

        for (var i = car.Make.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if (car.Make[i].ColourCode == 'G') {
                return car.Make[i].Name;
            }
        }
        return '';
    }
```

car.Make[i] is being calculated on another method and is showing the result of service call. That's why I have car.Make == null this should be true if the call hasn't happened.

When I have more calls to GetStatus() function some of them returns '' as result always even after some time when the whole array Make is being calculated.

Comment: So, you have some async call that generates the `car.Make` array.... and what is the question? Also, you should never have watched expressions (like `ng-show` or `ng-bind` or `{{..}}`) create side effects. Not to mention, that these expressions should be blazingly fast - really, just getters - and definitely not do any sort of for loops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I have more calls to GetStatus() function some of them returns '' as result always even after some time when the whole array Make is being calculated

Based on the code you have provided this can only happen if `car.Make == null` (which I think you already know) OR no make has color code `G` (I think this is the insight you are looking for).